# Chef cookbook creation with future upgrades in mind

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

If we create a chef cookbook to install Software packages (rpms, msi and exe) and if few days next version of the software released , then how do we plan for updating the cookbook.
Is there any common design pattern for this? any best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Its totally depends on the cookbook structure and your project need.

You can write a multiple versions of the same cookbook to do the installation of different executable versions (rpm, msi & exe).

or you can define each and everything in attribute as a variable and try to write a generic recipe which does the installation for you and whenever you got a new version of your executable then you have to update only once in a attribute variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.